# Should I follow WebApi route convention?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

Should I follow WebApi route convention?

I want to change my default route config (`api/{controller}/{id}`) to `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Is it ok to add `{action}` placeholder to my route?

What is the **pros/cons** of default WebApi route?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can have action names in your routes and use them. 
First, you have to add the following to your **WebApiConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ActionApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Be sure to add this before the default route or else it will not work.
Then add **ActionName** attribute in your controller methods

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Thumbnail")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetThumbnailImage(int id);
}
```

Then your route will be **/api/Products/Thumbnail**

For more info check the Routing by Action Name from [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Be sure to marks as answer if this helped you :)

By using Custom Action Names, you can move beyond the HTTP verbs in your controllers and have customized methods available in the API